# Overwrite a Map Service on ArcGIS Server in Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, map-service

I tried to automate the overwriting of an existing map service using a stand-alone Python script.

I mirrored the Esri's sample scripts. But when I ran it, the second print statement was never executed. However, when I ran the same script from the Python window inside ArcMap, the script ran as expected.

```
import arcpy

wrkspc = 'C:/GIS_Projects/'
mxd_name = 'Test.mxd'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(wrkspc + mxd_name)
server_con = 'GIS Servers/arcgis on myserver_6443 (admin)'
service = 'Test'
sddraft = wrkspc + service + '.sddraft'
sd_file = wrkspc + service + '.sd'
print 'local variables set'

analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mxd, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', server_con, True, None, 'test', 'test')
print 'SDdraft file created'
```

Comment: To me it looks like a standalone script python can't make sense of 'GIS Servers/arcgis on myserver_6443 (admin)' as a path. Change it to a full path name or copy the connection file into 'C:/GIS_Projects' Also try wrapping your code in a try catch clock. It will help with debugging.

Comment: I tried to use r'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcCatalog\arcgis on myserver_6443 (publisher).ags' as the connection file. But that didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: add some error handling to see what the error message being given is: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: also try setting overwrite to true arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Comment: @Dowlers error handling can get in the way of testing - if there is no error and no print happening then I doubt error handling will present anything new.

Comment: @Midavalo maybe I'm misreading it, Are we sure there is no error?

Comment: Based on your connectionfile, your server is setup on port 6443, a secure server. Do you have a proper security certificate installed on the server? If not, when the CreateMapSDDraft command runs outside ArcMap it'll get back a security warning dialog that it cannot do anything with. Inside ArcMap you would have got this as well, but clicked "ignore" or "ok". Do you get that security warning in ArcMap in a fresh session?

Comment: @KHibma The server does use a self-signed certificate, but I don't see any security warnings when the script was run in ArcMap.

Comment: If you dont get a security warning when making the initial connection then this probably isnt the issue.

Answer (score 3):

When I run the following it produces the `.sddraft` file as expected.  I made a couple of changes to your script

- I used `os.path.join` to create my folder paths (which possibly didn't change anything in the outputs but just ensures folders are constructed properly)
- Added a `.ags` on the end of the `server_con`

```py
import arcpy, os

wrkspc = r'C:\GIS_Projects'
mxd_name = 'Test.mxd'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(wrkspc, mxd_name))
server_con = r'GIS Servers\arcgis on myserver_6443 (admin).ags'
service = 'Test'
sddraft = os.path.join(wrkspc, "{}.sddraft".format(service))
sd_file = os.path.join(wrkspc, "{}.sd".format(service))
print 'local variables set'

analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mxd, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', server_con, True, None, 'test', 'test')
print 'SDdraft file created'
```

This printed both `print` lines, and output a `Test.sddraft` file.

I also tested without the `.ags` and the script still ran as expected.  You may need to confirm your folders and files exist as per your script.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the script. I tested it on my end. The second print statement still doesn't get executed. But when I ran the same script on another machine, it ran as expected. Thinking maybe this is related to some settings on the first machine. Still need to figure out what that is.